# Implementação de Classe em Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientação-a-objetos

Galera, desenvolvi a pouco tempo um joguinho de passa ou repassa de forma procedural (o código está ridículo). Estou querendo melhorá-lo para colocar em meu portfólio. Estou tentando implementar com orientação a objetos, seria o caso ou apenas uma melhora no código já basta? Caso o mais indicado seja utilizar OO, estou fazendo de forma correta, logicamente e sintaticamente?

Como está (funcionando):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

  var i = 0;//Usada para passar as perguntas
  var valorPergunta = 50;//armazena o valor valor da pergunta, pode ser alterado quando uma equipe passar.
  var vez = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1); //Define a equipe que começa o jogo
  var pontoum = 0; //pontos da equipe1
  var pontodois = 0; //pontos da equipe2
  var passadas = 0;
  $('#valor_pergunta').html(valorPergunta);
  $('#pontoum').html(pontoum);
  $('#pontodois').html(pontodois);
  $('#pagadesafio').prop('disabled', true);

  jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'consulta.php' + location.search,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(returnjson) {
          /*Coloquei tudo nessa maldita função porque a merda do JSON SÓ FUNCIONA DENTRO DA MERDA DO escopo do ajax
           ENTÃO VAI ASSIM MESMO.
          */
          //Exibe os dados de primeira
          $('#id_pergunta').html(returnjson[i].id_pergunta);
          $('#pergunta_jogo').html(returnjson[i].pergunta);
          $('#desafio_jogo').html(returnjson[i].desafio);
          $('#resposta_jogo').html(returnjson[i].resposta);
          $('#equipeum').prepend(returnjson.equipeum);
          $('#equipedois').prepend(returnjson.equipedois);
          if (vez === 1){
            alert("A Equipe " + returnjson.equipeum + " iniciará o jogo");
          } else{
            alert("A Equipe " + returnjson.equipedois + " iniciará o jogo");
          }


          function timer(){
            segundos = 60;
            var intervalo = setInterval(conta, 1000);
               function conta() {
               segundos--;
               $('#timer').html(segundos);
              //proxima();

            if (segundos <= 40 && segundos>=20){
              $('#gatilho').addClass("btn btn-warning");
            } else if(segundos<=20 ){
              $('#gatilho').addClass("btn btn-danger");

            }
            if (segundos === 0 && vez === 1 && passadas === 0){
              Alert("A equipe "+returnjson.equipeum+ " deve passar ou responder a pergunta.");
              clearInterval(intervalo);
           }
           else if (segundos === 0 && vez === 2 && passadas === 0){
             Alert("A equipe "+returnjson.equipedois+ " deve passar ou responder a pergunta.");
             clearInterval(intervalo);
           }
           else if (segundos === 0 && vez === 1 && passadas === 1){
             Alert("A pergunta não pode mais ser passada, a equipe "+returnjson.equipedois+ " deve passar ou responder a pergunta.");
             clearInterval(intervalo);
           }
           else if (segundos === 0 && vez === 2 && passadas === 1){
             Alert("A vez foi passada para:");
             clearInterval(intervalo);
           }
        }
      }

          function proxima(){

            var json = Object.keys(returnjson).length - 3;//Menos dois pq ele recebe as equipes no mesmo json

            $('#respondidas').html(i);
            $('#total').html(json);

            passadas = 0;
            valorPergunta = 50;
            $('#valor_pergunta').html(valorPergunta);
            i++;
            $('#id_pergunta').html(returnjson[i].id_pergunta);
            $('#pergunta_jogo').html(returnjson[i].pergunta);
            $('#desafio_jogo').html(returnjson[i].desafio);
            $('#resposta_jogo').html(returnjson[i].resposta);
            $('#pagadesafio').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#proxima').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#acertar').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#passar').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#pagadesafio').prop('disabled', true);
          }


      function passaVez() {
/*         switch (vez) {
           case 1:
             valorPergunta = valorPergunta + 50;
             $('#valor_pergunta').html(valorPergunta);
             passadas++;
             vez = 2;
          break;
           case 2:
             valorPergunta = valorPergunta + 50;
             $('#valor_pergunta').html(valorPergunta);
             passadas++;
             vez = 1;
           break;
}*/
        if (vez === 1 && passadas === 0) {
          alert("Pergunta Passada para a equipe" + returnjson.equipedois);
          valorPergunta = valorPergunta + 50;
          $('#valor_pergunta').html(valorPergunta);
          passadas++;
          vez = 2;
        }

        else if (vez === 2 && passadas === 0){
          alert("Pergunta Passada para a equipe" + returnjson.equipeum);
          valorPergunta = valorPergunta + 50;
          $('#valor_pergunta').html(valorPergunta);
          passadas++;
          vez = 1;
        }

        else if (vez == 1 && passadas == 1){
                alert("A pergunta já foi passada 2 vezes, a equipe " + returnjson.equipedois + " terá de pagar o desafio");
                $('#proxima').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#acertar').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#passar').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#pagadesafio').prop('disabled', false);
                valorPergunta = 50;
                $('#valor_pergunta').html(valorPergunta);
                passadas = 0;
                vez = 2;
            }
        else if (vez == 2 && passadas == 1 ){
                alert("A pergunta já foi passada 2 vezes, a equipe " + returnjson.equipeum + " terá de pagar o desafio");
                $('#proxima').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#acertar').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#passar').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#pagadesafio').prop('disabled', false);
                valorPergunta = 50;
                $('#valor_pergunta').html(valorPergunta);
                passadas = 0;
                vez = 1;
            }
          }

          function pagarDesafio(){
             switch (vez) {
               case 1:
                 $('#pontoum').html(pontoum = pontoum + valorPergunta);
                 valorPergunta = 0;
                 vez = 2;
                 proxima();
               break;
               case 2:
                 $('#pontodois').html(pontodois = pontodois + valorPergunta);
                 valorPergunta = 0;
                 vez = 1;
                 proxima();
               break;

             }

          }
          function acertar(){
                 if (vez === 1){
                   pontoum = pontoum + valorPergunta;
                   $('#pontoum').html(pontoum);
                   vez = 1;
                   proxima();
                   return true;
                 } else{
                   pontodois = pontodois + valorPergunta;
                   $('#pontodois').html(pontodois);
                   vez = 2;
                   proxima();
                   return true;
                 }
               }

               function errar(){
                 if (vez === 1){
                   alert("A equipe " +returnjson.equipeum+ " errou, ponto para a equipe "+returnjson.equipedois);
                   pontodois = pontodois + valorPergunta;
                   $('#pontodois').html(pontodois);
                   vez = 2;
                   proxima();
                   //proxima();
                 } else {
                   alert("A equipe " +returnjson.equipedois+ " errou, ponto para a equipe "+returnjson.equipeum);
                   pontoum = pontoum + valorPergunta;
                   $('#pontoum').html(pontoum);
                   vez = 1;
                   proxima();
                 }
               }
           function defineVencedor (){
             if (i == json && pontoum > pontodois){

               alert ("A equipe" +returnjson.equipeum+ " venceu o jogo!")
             } else if (i == json && pontodois > pontoum){
               alert("A equipe" +returnjson.equipedois+ " venceu o jogo!")
             } else if (i == json && pontodois == pontoum){
               alert("Deu empate");
             }
           }


          //Função que troca a vez de jogar ao clicar no botão passar
          $('#passar').click(function trocaVez(){
            passaVez();
          });
          $('#pagadesafio').click(function pagaDesafio(){
            pagarDesafio();
          });

          $('#acertar').click(function acertarPergunta(){
            acertar();
          });

          $('#errar').click(function errarPergunta(){
            errar();
          });

          $('#gatilho').click(function contarTempo(){
            timer();
          });


        },
        error: function(returnjson) {
            alert("Erro interno do servidor");
            window.location = 'Index.php';
        }
    });


 });
```

Classe que estou tentando implementar:

```
class equipe {
  var nome;
  var pontos;
  var vez;
  var acertos = 0;
  var erros = 0;
  var desafios = 0;

  function passaVez(){
   //A vez tem que ser passada para a outra instância do objeto equipe ao ser clicado no botão
  }

  function acertar(pergunta){
    this.ponto = this.ponto + pergunta;
    this.acertos++;
  }

  function errar(){
    this.erros++;
    passaVez();
  }

  function pagaDesafio(pergunta){
    this.desafios++;
    acertar(pergunta);
  }

  function get pontos(){
    return this.pontos;
  }

  function get erros(){
    return this.erros;
  }

  function get acertos(){
    return this.acertos;
  }
  function get desafios(){
    return this.desafios;
  }

}
```

Comment: da uma olhada nisso, a orientacao a objetos em javascript é totalmente diferente das outras linguagens, até por que não é 100% orientação a objetos.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: @jeffersonmelloolynyki eu estou tentando implementar de acordo com o ES6, conforme documentado pelo site da própria MOZILLA  https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: entendi, não cheguei a usar neste formato

Comment: De fato, ter no portfolio um código que possui o comentário "*Coloquei tudo nessa maldita função porque a merda do JSON SÓ FUNCIONA DENTRO DA MERDA DO escopo do ajax ENTÃO VAI ASSIM MESMO*" realmente não é uma coisa muito boa.

Comment: Sim @andersonCarlosWoss é de acabar com qualquer chance que eu teria com o avaliador kkkkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, Thiago

Apesar da ES6 permitir a criação de classes, o Javascript ainda é uma linguagem de paradigma funcional. A introdução da ES6 surgiu da necessidade do Javascript se comunicar com dados, APIs, entre outros. Por isso, a utilização de classes (que é apenas um dos maravilhosos recursos introduzidos pela ES6) é recomendada onde há necessidade de reutilizar código, deixar seu código mais testável, entre outros.

Quanto a sua classe, eu sugiro o seguinte:

```
class Equipe {
  constructor(args) {
    this.nome = args.nome;
    this.pontos = args.pontos;
    this.vez = args.vez;
    this.acertos = 0;
    this.erros = 0;
    this.desafios = 0;
  }

  passaVez() {
    // TODO
  }

  acertar(pergunta){
    this.ponto = this.ponto + pergunta;
    this.acertos++;
  }

  errar(){
    this.erros++;
    this.passaVez();
  }

  pagaDesafio(pergunta){
    this.desafios++;
    this.acertar(pergunta);
  }

  get pontos(){
    return this.pontos;
  }

  get erros(){
    return this.erros;
  }

  get acertos(){
    return this.acertos;
  }

  get desafios(){
    return this.desafios;
  }
}
```